# Joomla disable database error

Tags: joomla

I escape all input with db->escape method on joomla.
For example :

```
site.com/index.php?view=test&id=5'
```

In my model ,i use id in my query,
Query code:

```
$db= JFactory::getDBO();
$id = $db->escape($id);
$query="SELECT name FROM jos_test WHERE id=$id"                     
$database->setQuery($query);
$result = $database->loadResult();
```

Now,i add a ' to end of url
Joomla add a backslash before '.
But it's give syntax error and show table name.it is a security problem.
how to disable joomla sql syntax error?

```
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\'' at line 1 SQL=SELECT `name` FROM `jos_test` WHERE id=5\'
```

Comment: Do you have magic quotes turned on or off?

Comment: no,magic quote is off.

Comment: Ok, can you provide the code for your query please and add it to your initial question?

Answer (score 0):

You should be parsing your GET parameters using either 
[JRequest::getVar](http://docs.joomla.org/J1.5%3aRetrieving_and_Filtering_GET_and_POST_requests_with_JRequest%3a%3agetVar) method if this is an old Joomla 1.5 or 
using the [JInput](http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput) class in Joomla 2.5/3+.

```
$input=JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$id = $input->get('id', 0, 'INT');
```

This way you can be safe using them with database queries.
Also the correct way to do database queries is [described here](http://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase).

Finally be sure to [disable error reporting](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.2%3aGlobal_configuration) before going public by editing the configuration.php file. Change the `$error_reporting` parameter to `'None'`.

Comment: i disable error reporting,but joomla sql syntax error not disabled

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();    
$query = $db->getQuery(true);     
$query->select($db->quoteName('name'))
      ->from($db->quoteName('#__test'))
      ->where($db->quoteName('id') . ' = ' . $id);    
$db->setQuery($query);    
$results = $db->loadResult();
```

This uses up to date coding standards for database queries.

Hope this helps

Comment: When we use (int) if input not int,input set to 0;but only on numeric parameter,How to do this in string????

Comment: ID's should only ever be numeric, if you're using alphanumeric then this is the wrong approach. To make it a string, simply remove `(int)` from the code as I have done above in my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this (from table names i suppose you're using Joomla 1.5):

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$id = JRequest::getVar('id', 0, 'INT');

$query="SELECT name FROM #__test WHERE id = " . $id;
$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->loadResult();
```

In Joomla 3 you can use query builder and avoid depreached JRequest:

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$id = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('id', 0, 'INT');
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('name')
  ->from('#__test')
  ->where('id = ' . $id);
$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->loadResult();
```

Comment: Dont forget to escape

Comment: Actually JRequest or JInput does all the filtering / escaping and no need to escape additionally.

Comment: I was referring to the database table name "`#__test`" and the column name "`name`" :)